# CSS Translate and Scale on Y-Axis?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am taking an online course learning CSS and we are just covering CSS animations. I am trying to practice some of the things I learned (just basic transforms for now) by creating a small animation of a man walking towards the screen down a pathway.

Basically, I want to both translate and scale my image at the same time. I got this working fine, but now I also wanted to add some small rotation so that it looks like the man is slightly moving left and right. Here is my code in a jsfiddle, I don't know how to change the transform-origin so that the man is walking in a straight line on the Y-Axis, the scale makes him walk in a diagonal. I hope that makes sense...

The commented out part of the code includes the scale, as soon as that is added back, and the part without scale is commented out, it acts funny and I'm thinking this has to do with the origin?

https://jsfiddle.net/qLLqdxbm/

HTML:

```
<div class="man-scale">
  <img class="man-walk" src="http://clipart-library.com/img/1184697.png">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.man-walk {
    width: 100px;
    height: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50px;

    animation-name: man-walk;
    animation-duration: 0.45s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes man-walk {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    25% {
        transform: rotate(1.5deg);
    }

    50% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    75% {
        transform: rotate(-1.5deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

.man-scale {
    width: 100px;
    height: 125px;

    animation-name: man-scale;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

/* define the animation */
@keyframes man-scale {
/*     0% {
        transform: translate(0px, 5px) scale(1.1);
    }

    25% {
        transform: translate(0px, 15px) scale(1.5);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translate(0px, 25px) scale(1.7);
    }

    75% {
        transform: translate(0px, 35px) scale(2.0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0px, 45px) scale(2.3);
    } */

    0% {
        transform: translate(0px, 5px);
    }

    25% {
        transform: translate(0px, 15px);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translate(0px, 25px);
    }

    75% {
        transform: translate(0px, 35px);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(0px, 45px);
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am using rotation, scale and translate...the scale is being used to enlarge the image as it is getting closer, I'm not sure what you mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time you scale the image along X and Y, the origin shifts in both dimensions by a specific offset. If you can compensate for that offset in the X dimension then a vertical animation could be achieved.

In this case in first keyframe the scale increased by 0.1 which is `100 * 0.1 = 10px` now origin got offset by `5px` in X dimension, compensating in terms of `translateX(-5px)`. Similarly for all the other keyframes.

If you want a faster animation in the Y dimension just increase the Y translate values without touching the X translation values.

```css
.man-walk {
    width: 100px;
    height: 125px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50px;

    animation-name: man-walk;
    animation-duration: 0.45s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes man-walk {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    25% {
        transform: rotate(1.5deg);
    }

    50% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    75% {
        transform: rotate(-1.5deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

.man-scale {
    width: 100px;
    height: 125px;

    animation-name: man-scale;
    animation-duration: 2s;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

/* define the animation */
@keyframes man-scale {
     0% {
        transform: translate(-5px, 30px) scale(1.1);
    }

    25% {
        transform: translate(-20px, 70px) scale(1.4);
    }

    50% {
        transform: translate(-35px, 120px) scale(1.7);
    }

    75% {
        transform: translate(-50px, 180px) scale(2.0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translate(-65px, 250px) scale(2.3);
    } 
}
```

```html
<div class="man-scale">
  <img class="man-walk" src="http://clipart-library.com/img/1184697.png">
</div>
```

There might be some advanced CSS techniques to calculate the offset automatically.

Comment: Thanks! That does exactly what I want, and your explanation helped me understand what is happening. One further question, how do I control how far in the y-axis the animation will go? Adjusting the second value in the translate() doesn't seem to have much effect.

Comment: I have increased it in 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 increments. You can increase them further to see how it goes.

Comment: Sorry to bug you again about this, but how does the equation you mentioned above get affected if you change the left, top coordinates when the page first loads? I tried playing around with those and now the translate + scale goes on a diagonal again. For example, if you change top to 315px and left to 415px.

Comment: Don't change the `top` and `left` on the image. Make the parent div `absolute` and then set which ever `top` and `left` you want to. The reason it is going diagonal is because the center is shifted as opposed to `50px = 100px/2` earlier.